# Python: List of input variables in a parameterized function

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am tryin to get a list of values from the user and use them in a function, This is my code :

```
def functionwithList(*words):

    for i in words:
        print(f"this is part of the words list: {i}")



param1,param2 = functionwithList(input('enter two numbers').split())
```

When I execute the code I am getting the following output along with the Cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType Object

```
enter two numbers1 2
this is part of the words list: ['1', '2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\DataScience_BootCamp\PythonBootcampSession2\Demo\Session_4.py", line 16, in <module>
    param1,param2 = functionwithList(input('enter two numbers').split())
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Could someone please explain what is wrong here?

Comment: What do you expect `functionwithList` to return?

Answer (score 0):

If `words` is supposed to be a list of strings then change

```
def functionwithList(*words):
```

to

```
def functionwithList(words):
```

Also `functionwithList` does not `return` anything, so there is nothing unpack when you call the function

```
param1,param2 = functionwithList(...
```

You would want to modify your function to

```
def functionwithList(words):
    for i in words:
        print(f"this is part of the words list: {i}")
    return words
```

Comment: The suggested modification and consequent unpacking will only work if the returned list contains exactly 2 elements

Answer (score 0):

Either remove `param1,param2` from the function call.
Or add a return in the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return list from the function then simply use have to return this

```
def functionwithList(*words):
    for i in words:
        print(f"this is part of the words list: {i}")
    return words[0]

param1,param2 = functionwithList(input('enter two numbers').split())
```

this is because you are considering words are argument instead of parameter.